# How to include javascript place holder in Jinja 2 place holder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to embed this feature in my Flask app --> [Scattered Polaroid Gallery](https://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Stacked-Scattered-Polaroid-Gallery-with-jQuery-CSS3.html)

So, I have a template (Jinja2), where I am displaying a stack of images. To access the images I am using Flask's url_for() command which uses the symbol ---> {{}}. In the Javascript file which is supposed to dynamically load the images, the same symbol is being used i.e ----> {{}}. I want to know how can I use Javascript's {{}} along with Flask/Jinja 2 {{}}

Below is the Javascript function that replaces every instance of {{img}} with the actual file name.

```js
function addPhotos() {
  var template = select('#wrap').innerHTML;
  var html = [];
  var nav = [];
  for (i=0; i<1; i++) {
    
    var _html = template.replace('{{index}}', i)
    .replace('img', data[i].img)
    .replace('{{caption}}', data[i].caption)
    .replace('{{desc}}', data[i].desc);
    html.push(_html);
    nav.push('<span id="nav_'+i+'" class="i" onclick ="turn(select(\'#photo_'+i+'\'))">&nbsp;</span>');
  }
  html.push('<div class="nav">'+nav.join('')+'</div>');
  select('#wrap').innerHTML = html.join('');
  sort(random([0, data.length]));
}
```

```html
<div class="mainPage" id="fullpage">
    <div class="first section">
        <div class="wrap" id="wrap">
            <div class="photo photo_front" id="photo_{{index}}" onclick="turn(this)">
                <div class="photo-wrap">
                    <div class="side side-front">
                        <p class="image">
                            <!-- <img src="photo/{{img}}"> -->
                            <img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='photo/{{img}}') }}">
                             <!-- .replace('{{img}}', data[i].img) -->
                        </p>
                        <p class="caption">{{caption}}</p>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="side side-back">
                        <p class="desc">{{desc}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Above is the template that uses both Javascript and Jinja2 {{}}.

The following error is shown in the Chrome debug console.

[image: Error]

Below is my folder structure for the Flask app -

[image: Flask app]

PS - I have tried using relative path for the image folder instead of url_for() function for ex-  `<img src="../static/photo/{{img}}">` but it failed as well.

In that case, the following error was shown -

[image: Error2]

Please help.

### **EDIT -**

After having used `&quot;` , the following error resulted.

[image: New error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the curly brackets by using quotes. Since you need to do this inside an html attribute `src` you will have to escape these quotes as well since quotes are used already inside the HTML attribute and the way to achieve that is byusing `&quot;`

Take a look at the `img` tag `src` attribute below. If you want to escape the Jinja curly brackets that are not part of an HTML attribute then you can use jinja `{% raw %}` block (see how I surrounded `{{caption}}` )

```
<div class="mainPage" id="fullpage">
    <div class="first section">
        <div class="wrap" id="wrap">
            <div class="photo photo_front" id="photo_{{index}}" onclick="turn(this)">
                <div class="photo-wrap">
                    <div class="side side-front">
                        <p class="image">

                            <img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='photo/&quot;{{img}}&quot;') }}">

                        </p>
                        <p class="caption">{% raw %}{{'caption'}}{% endraw %}</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="side side-back">
                        <p class="desc">{% raw %}{{desc}}{% endraw %}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Okay I tried it out but it seems like the &quot; is not working. I have edited the new error message in the upload section.

Comment: Ok I think that your error has nothing to do with the problem you were describing. Your JavaScript code fails before it reaches to replacing `{{img}}`. Looks like your `select('#wrap')` is null and you are calling `select('#wrap').className` on 'null' you need to first resolve this error and then try again without the use of `&quote;`

Comment: Okay So i have made it work somehow. I'll update the answer. Your input regarding using escape sequence was really helpful. I used {% raw %} which is escape command for jinja2 to achieve the same. I'll accept your answer though since it indirectly led me to solce it.